# How can I check that program works with standard I/O streams&

Tags: java, io

It is possible to reassign standard input/output streams using [`System.setIn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn-java.io.InputStream-) and [`System.setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) methods.

I want to check if current input/output streams are standard.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Doing so isn't possible. There is no "what file does file handle 1 (stdout) actually point to".

Comment: `System.in` and `System.out` are "standard" by definition. Why do you want (or _think_ you want) to reassign them, and how do you think it would help you to know if the current streams are standard?  In other words, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KevinAnderson in my case input/output streams are reassigned in tests. Then need to be reassigned to standard after tests, using `System.setIn(System.in), System.setOut(System.out)`. After tests I need to verify, that they are actually reassigned to standards

Comment: Once you've done `System.setIn(newIn);`, then `System.in == newIn` and you've lost whatever `System.in` was before. You need to first **save the original values** of `System.in` and `System.out` before you reassign them in your tests.  After the test, reassign standard input and standard output using those saved values.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use reflection, this method will do:

```
private boolean isStandardOutput()
{
    boolean x;
    try
    {
        Field field=FilterOutputStream.class.getDeclaredField("out");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value=System.out;
        do
        {
            value=field.get(value);
        }
        while (value instanceof FilterOutputStream);
        if (value instanceof FileOutputStream)
        {
            Field fieldFd=FileOutputStream.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
            fieldFd.setAccessible(true);
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor=(FileDescriptor)fieldFd.get(value);
            x=(fileDescriptor == FileDescriptor.out);
        }
        else
        {
            x=false;
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        x=false;
    }
    return x;
}
```

The idea behind is quite simple: It unwraps succesively the `System.out` value until it finds a `FileOutputStream` value. Then, gets its inner `FileDescriptor` and checks it against `FileDescriptor.out` (which, being a constant value, cannot be modified).

Analog algorithms could be used for `System.in` and `System.err`.